# String comparison in Java Weird

Tags: java, string, compare

Hi I have a strange problem with my code and I cant figure out whats wrong.

I have:

ArrayList called players

Class: Player

Class: Name

Player class contains Name class which contains 3 Strings FirstName MiddleName LastName

The problem is when im trying to do

```
For( int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
{
    if( players.get(i).getName().getFirst() == "First1")
    {
         // Some Code 
    }

    System.out.printf(players.get(i).getName().getFirst());
}
```

If statement is never true, weird thing is when im using system.out to check as below

```
System.out.printf(players.get(i).getName().getFirst());
```

it returns:

First1 First2 First3

getName() method returns object name and getFirst() returns String FirstName

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Please refer this [LINK][1] for detailed info about String comparison.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: == compares if they are literally the same object, `.equals()`  tests if they "look the same"

Comment: @maheshrpm only minimarkdown works in comments. Of the form `[see example here](www.example.com)`

Answer (score 4):

Never EVER EVER EVER compare Strings with ==. use .equals() instead.
"==" compares references of Strings. .equals() compares actual values.

Answer (score 3):

To compare String objects in java use `.equals()` method instead of `"=="` operator. If you want ignore the case use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` method.

For String comparison you should use like this

```
if( "First1".equals(players.get(i).getName().getFirst()))
```